# Error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'const char *'.How to solve this error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I get rid of this error and other while compiling the below code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 256 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  char path[300];
  bool FindFilesFromFolder();
   getchar();
   return 0;
  } 

bool FindFilesFromFolder()

{
 HANDLE            hFile;
 WIN32_FIND_DATA   FindFileData;
 std::vector<char> fileList;

  char chFolderpath[_MAX_PATH];
  CString strExtension   = _T("*.B11");

  strcpy(chFolderpath, _T("F:\\test\\"));
  strcat(chFolderpath, strExtension);

 hFile = FindFirstFile(chFolderpath, &FindFileData);

  if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

  AfxMessageBox(_T("Inavlid file handle."));
  return false;
  }

  CString filepath;

   do
   {

    filepath.Format(_T("%s%s"), _T("F:\\test\\"), FindFileData.cFileName);
    fileList.push_back(filepath);

   } while(FindNextFile(hFile, &FindFileData));


   return true;

  }
```

Yes this is an example to know the correct usage of `findfirstfile()`. I got `strcpy` errors too.

> `Error:error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'const char *'. Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast.`
>
> `Error: error C2664: 'strcat' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'ATL::CString' to 'const char *'. No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called.`
>
> `Error:error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ATL::CString' to 'const char &' with`

It gives all conversion errors; how to solve these errors?

Comment: You can't use declare `char` arrays when working with Unicode strings. Use either the `TCHAR` macro to handle it automatically, or declare it explicitly as a wide string with `wchar_t`.

Comment: Please look at the preview pane and fix your formatting before submission. It only takes a moment of your time, and saves a few of ours.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title says `strcpy` but your code and errors have `FindFirstFile`?

Anyway, declaring your buffer like this will help:

```
TCHAR chFolderpath[_MAX_PATH];
```

<strike>Then you will want to use `_tcscpy` and `_tcscat` instead of `strcpy` and `strcat`.</strike>  Even better, `#include <strsafe.h>` and use [the string functions that protect against buffer overrun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468908.aspx).

Regarding `AfxMessageBox`, this is not a standard Windows function.  It's part of MFC, I suppose you cut and pasted from an example that used MFC.  Windows has a [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) function which you can use, but you'll need to supply all the parameters (parent window, message, title, buttons).

Comment: Yes this is an example to know the correct usuageof findfirstfile().