# how to represent the file extension in StringCbCatN() 

Tags: c, visual-c++

Here is the piece of code which display all files in the folder.

```
StringCbCopyN (DirSpec, BUFSIZE, argv[1], length_of_arg+1); 
StringCbCatN (DirSpec, BUFSIZE, "\\*", 3); //this is the exact line to display all the files in folderNow i want to select all .b11 extension files in console window.
```

I tired these below thingd which couldnt work for me.Kindly give me any idea or suggestion to select these extension files.

```
StringCbCatN (DirSpec, BUFSIZE, "\*.b11", 3); 


StringCbCatN (DirSpec, BUFSIZE, "*.b11", 3);
StringCbCatN (DirSpec, BUFSIZE, "\\.b11", 3);
```

Comment: Haven't you searched on Net ?

Comment: *"but still get the errors."* **What errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hari, I already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090272/103167) that to use `TCHAR` strings, you should be using [the functions in `#include <strsafe.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468908.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

VC2008 supports strcpy(), strcat(), etc; they are declared in "string.h".

It *should* work.

Q: Could you please cut/paste the following:

1) an instance of where you're using "strcpy()" in your code?

2) the exact error message (which should correspond to the line you cut/pasted above)

Thank you in advance

**ADDENDUM:**

I happen to have VS2008 installed on my laptop, and verified strcpy() and friends work just fine:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *hello = "Hello world";
  char s[80];
  strcpy (s, hello);
  printf ("%s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

<= THIS COMPILES AND RUNS WITHOUT ERROR